# Appending lines after copying text from a file using Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following code that copies content from a text file and adds it to an XML file. Since XML file should have a specific format, I have added a few write statements. After copying the content from text file, I want some more closing tags to be added so that the XML structure will be complete. But, I am facing issues while doing this. Problem is, after copying each line, the closing tags get added. But, I do not want this. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks.

Requirement: Copy content from text file to XML file, and then add a few closing tags.
Code written:

```
with open("hello.txt") as f:
    with open('copy.xml', 'w') as f1:
        f1.write("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n")
        f1.write("<!DOCTYPE concept PUBLIC \"-//OASIS//DTD DITA Concept//EN\" \"concept.dtd\">\n")
        f1.write("<concept id =\"")
        f1.write("\">\n")
        f1.write("<title></title>")
        f1.write("<conbody>\n")
        f1.write("<codeblock>\n")
        for line in f:
            f1.write(line)
            f1.write("</codeblock>\n")
            f1.write("</conbody>\n")
            f1.write("</concept>")
```

Content of hello.txt file -

```
efg

nhytkkoohhhss
```

Output that I am getting now -

```
<!DOCTYPE concept PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Concept//EN" "concept.dtd">
<concept id ="">
<title></title><conbody>
<codeblock>
abc
</codeblock>
</conbody>
</concept>
</codeblock>
</conbody>
</concept>efg
</codeblock>
</conbody>
</concept>
</codeblock>
</conbody>
</concept>nhytkkoohhhss
</codeblock>
</conbody>
</concept>
```

Output that I need -

```
<!DOCTYPE concept PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Concept//EN" "concept.dtd">
<concept id ="">
<title></title><conbody>
<codeblock>
abc

efg

nhytkkoohhhss
</codeblock>
</conbody>
</concept>
```

Comment: Have you tried unindenting everything below ````f1.write(line)````

Comment: Perfect. Never thought it would be such a simple fix. Thanks.

Comment: Have written up as an answer to mark the question as solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is a result of the closing tags being run during the for loop, unindenting them will fix this:

```py
with open("hello.txt") as f:
    with open('copy.xml', 'w') as f1:
        f1.write("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n")
        f1.write("<!DOCTYPE concept PUBLIC \"-//OASIS//DTD DITA Concept//EN\" \"concept.dtd\">\n")
        f1.write("<concept id =\"")
        f1.write("\">\n")
        f1.write("<title></title>")
        f1.write("<conbody>\n")
        f1.write("<codeblock>\n")
        for line in f:
            f1.write(line)
        f1.write("</codeblock>\n")
        f1.write("</conbody>\n")
        f1.write("</concept>")
```